# Trying to fix an #ifeq statement in a MediaWiki template

Tags: parsing, templates, if-statement, mediawiki

I'm trying to make a spoiler notice template in Fandom, with an expandable text section below it.  I've hit a wall trying to get the variables and #ifeq statement to work.

The way this is supposed to work, the first parameter is the story type and controls the #ifeq statement. If the user puts "short story" into parameter 1, it wraps the title (parameter 2) in double quotes (""). Any other input (it defaults to "novel") italicizes it. The third param is a text section, what you're flagging as a spoiler, that defaults to hidden using built-in MediaWiki classes ([from here](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/Help:Collapsing)).

```
{| style="width:100%; margin-top:1em; border:1px solid #999; font-size:90%; text-align:center;"
|-
! style="padding:0.2em 0.5em; background-color:red;" nowrap="nowrap" class="color1" | ''SPOILER WARNING<nowiki>!!!</nowiki>''
|-
| This section contains spoilers for the {{{1|novel}}} {{#ifeq: {{{1|}}}|short story|{{{1}}} "[[{{{2|{{PAGENAME}}}}}]]"|{{{1}}}{{{''[[{{{2|{{PAGENAME}}}}}]]''}}. Expand at your own risk.
|-
|}<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed">
{{{3}}}
</div>
```

Source: https://aeon14.fandom.com/wiki/Template:Spoiler

Comment: I do not understand why ifeq. if seems sufficient in your position. Can you elaborate with 2 distincts examples ?

Comment: @Camille: According to this... https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions 

... #if only tests whether the parameter is an empty string.

Comment: don't you have a bit too much brackets in the "if not" part of your ifeq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. It turned out I had some extraneous brackets in there, plus I had mistakenly left a second copy of parameter 1 in both fields. This is the fixed code:

```
{| style="width:100%; margin-top:1em; border:1px solid #999; font-size:90%; text-align:center;"
|-
! style="padding:0.2em 0.5em; background-color:red;" nowrap="nowrap" class="color1" | ''SPOILER WARNING<nowiki>!!!</nowiki>''
|-
| This section contains spoilers for the {{{1|novel}}} {{#ifeq: {{{1|}}}|short story|"[[{{{2|{{PAGENAME}}}}}]]"|''[[{{{2|{{PAGENAME}}}}}]]''}}. Expand at your own risk.
|-
|}<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed">
{{{3}}}
</div>
```